# Get values of div, check if the value is in td, if so, change class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to return a value(s) within a div, then check another div to see if the values exist. If they do, change the class of the link. The loop is working great. I need to now check the other field.

```
var cart = '';
$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').each(function (i, div) {
    cart += ' ' + $(div).text();
});

if(cart != "")
{
   //do something
}
```

I need to see if the value returned by cart is in a table value:

```
<td class="views-field views-field-title">
    <a href="/accessory/oi-01">
        <span class="assess-title">OI-01</span>
    </a>
    <p>
        <a class="add-to-quote" href="/cart/add/3">Add to Quote</a>
    </p>
</td>
```

If the values match, I need to change the class from "add-to-quote" to "added-to-quote". The example with for the td, is showing one of many that are on the page with various other numbers. I am trying to find only the one that matches the value returned by cart. Any thoughts???

Thanks!

Comment: Which value needs to match? Also, your markup is invalid because you have an open `<a>` tag without a matching `</a>` tag. Can you please indicate where the closing tag should be?

Comment: As Travis asked, please specify *which* value in the table you need to check against?  Maybe, give an example: "Suppose the DIV says _____. Then I need to check inside the href in an a tag and see if the text says _____"   Something like that. (*I am just guessing at what you are trying to check because it's not clear in your question.*)

Comment: My apologies, I did not include the full html markup. If the returned value of cart, in this instance, had OI-01 then it would change the class of the "add-to-quote" since the "access-title" matches returned cart value.

Comment: There's alot missing here. Can you place the actual html markup and your current block of js code in a fiddle @ www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have added the code to jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/RarYt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
if(cart != "")
{
    //Find all the "assess-title"s
    $('.views-field.views-field-title > a > .assess-title').each(function (i, span) {
        var $span = $(span);
        if(cart.indexOf($span.html())!=-1){//The cart contains it?
            $span.parent().next().find("a.add-to-quote").addClass("theClassToAdd").html("Added to Quote");
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNkd6/1/)

Comment: How would I change the text from "add to quote" to "added to quote? I appreciate the help! This worked perfectly.

Comment: Last question, I appreciate all of your help. how would I apply this logic to:  
<td>
<strong>
OI-01
<br>
</strong>
<a class="add-to-quote" href="/cart/add/244">Add to Quote  </a>
</td>